How can I update a variable within my Http4s service every set interval of time?
I am trying to continually refresh a value after a set interval of time within an Http4s service. Up until now it's been defined as just a val that maintains its initial value. I would like to continue treating it as an assigned value (as opposed to an effect, for example), but to allow for it to change its value on a set schedule.
I've produced what I think is a minimal example, where freshValue needs to be regenerated every X amount of time (right now it's just a val initialized to a single call to a function that generates a new value).
package com.example

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}
import cats.syntax.all._
import cats.Monad
import org.http4s.blaze.server.BlazeServerBuilder
import org.http4s.dsl.Http4sDsl
import org.http4s.{HttpApp, HttpRoutes}

object ExampleService extends IOApp {
  val freshValue: Int = generateNewValue() // re-generate every X minutes

  def generateNewValue(): Int = scala.util.Random.nextInt(42)

  def routes[F[_]: Monad]: HttpRoutes[F] = {
    val dsl = Http4sDsl[F]
    import dsl._

    HttpRoutes.of[F] {
      case GET -> Root / "ping"        => Ok("pong")
      case GET -> Root / "fresh-value" => Ok(s"$freshValue")
    }
  }

  def allRoutes[F[_]: Monad]: HttpApp[F] =
    routes.orNotFound

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val forkJoinPool = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool(8))

    BlazeServerBuilder[IO]
      .withExecutionContext(forkJoinPool)
      .bindHttp(1234, "localhost")
      .withHttpApp(allRoutes)
      .resource
      .use(_ => IO.never)
      .as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}

I would prefer to continue handling it as its original type, instead of an effect. If it needs to be an effect, I'd prefer it to be effect-agnostic (not necessarily an IO). The value itself that refreshes (along with other vals that depend on it) is defined deep inside a case class which is referred to throughout the app. I'd prefer not to alter usage of the case class and its attributes/methods, which have been kept effect-free (as they never had any reason to change from the start of the service). I would be fine creating a new instance/copy of the case class after each interval of time has elapsed. I'd be open to solutions involving fs2, cats/cats-effect, and http4s.
The actual use case is that a token needs to be refreshed once every 12 hours, and there exists a case class that defines a handful of clients and attributes that would need to be regenerated when it's time for a new token. (Basically, it is a case class containing a set of resources, some of which depend on the token itself.)
In my search for a solution, I've encountered usage of fs2 Streams that can create an effect that gets evaluated after every set interval of time, but I'm having trouble adapting it so that I can be left with a pure value that I can use as its intended type:
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO}
import cats.syntax.all._
import fs2.Stream
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val freshValue: IO[ExitCode] = Stream.awakeEvery[IO](3.seconds)
  .evalMap(_ => IO({ println("triggered another operation"); scala.util.Random.nextInt(10) }))
  .compile
  .drain
  .as(ExitCode.Success)

I'm not sure how I could instead create an effect containing the type that I want (not an ExitCode), and obviously I don't want to call something like freshValue.unsafeRunSync() to be able to access the value itself within a case class that doesn't use effects. I'm wondering how using this fs2 Stream would affect the vals and case classes that depend on its value, if those need to become an effect, or if a different approach altogether makes more sense here.
Apologies if my requirements don't make sense, I'm still getting used to programming with Cats, and my organization doesn't have others with experience with these frameworks, so I'm learning as I go.

TL;DR; you want to use a Ref

This problem is actually very common.
I am going to share the general solution to it by steps, and then you can adapt it to your specific use case. Also, I personally prefer to use IO directly but you can easily modify the code to be in tagless final style; i.e. F[_].
1. Compute the value
We first need a function that is able to compute the value you need.
Such function may either be independent of the current state, or may want to receive the current state as input in order to produce the new one.
val generateFreshValue: IO[Value] = ...

// Or.
def generateFreshValue(oldValue: Value): IO[Value] = ...

// Tagless final:
def generateFreshValue[F[_]: TC]: F[OldValue] = ...
// Where TC is whatever constraint you need.

// Also, you may want to put this inside a trait so you can mock it for tests.
trait FreshValueGenerator[F[_]]:
  def generateFreshValue: F[Value] // IO[Value]

2. Adapt value usage
Make the computations that depend on this value accept it as a parameter rather than getting it from a global place.
// Do this:
def foo(value: Value, ...): Foo = {
  ...
}

// Rather than this:
def foo(...): Foo = {
  val value = SomeGlobalObject.freshValue
  ...
}

3. Use a Ref to contain the value
Since the value will be mutating over time, we need to encapsulate it into something that can handle mutation in a concurrent environment safely. cats-effect already provides that, is called a Ref:
val createValueHolder: IO[Ref[IO, Value]] = IO.ref(initialValue)

// TF style:
def createValueHolder[F[_]: Concurrent]: F[Ref[F, Value]] = Ref.of[F](initialValue)

4. Modify the layer above the usage of value to get it from the Ref
In the second step, we refactored all usages of the value to request it as an input parameter. That would have caused the upper layers to either do the same, or refer to a constant / global / dummy value.
Now, we are going to refactor those to get the value from the Ref and then use it.
// Do this:
final class Logic(valueHolder: Ref[IO, Value]) {
  def run(...): IO[Unit] =
    valueHolder.get.flatMap { freshValue =>
      val foo = foo(freshValue, ...)
      ...
    }
}

// Rather than this:
final class Logic {
  def run(...): IO[Unit] = {
    val foo = foo(someGlobalFreshValue, ...)
    ...
  }
}

5. Make a background process to refresh the value every X minutes.
First we define a program that refresh the value ever so often:
def refreshValue(valueHolder: Ref[IO, Value], refreshEvery: Duration): IO[Unit] =
  (
    IO.sleep(refreshEvery) >>
    generateFreshValue.flatMap(valueHolder.set)
  ).foreverM

And then you can put it to run in the background of your app.
There are many ways to do that, but I prefer to use the background combinator and composing resources.

You may want to pack the refresh process and the Ref together in a single module.


And that is all you need really.
Now, I will apply all that on your sample code, adding some structure that allows the code to be easily modifiable.
import cats.Monad
import cats.effect.{Async, Concurrent, IO, IOApp, Ref}
import cats.effect.syntax.all._
import cats.syntax.all._
import org.http4s.dsl.Http4sDsl
import org.http4s.server.Server
import org.http4s.ember.server.EmberServerBuilder

object ExampleService extends IOApp.Simple {
  private val app: Resource[IO, Server] =
    for {
      valueGenerator <- ValueGenerator.make[IO]
      valueHolder <- ValueHolder.make[IO](valueGenerator)
      logic = Logic.make(valueGetter)
      server <- HttpServer.make[IO](logic)
    } yield server

  override final val run: IO[Unit] =
    app.useForever
}

trait ValueGenerator[F[_]] {
  def generateFreshValue: F[Value]
}

object ValueGetter {
  def make[F[_]]: Resource[F, ValueGetter[F]] =
    ...
}

trait ValueHolder[F[_]] {
  def getValue: F[Value]
}

object ValueHolder {
  def make[F[_]: Concurrent](
    valueGenerator: ValueGenerator[F]
  ): Resource[F, ValueHolder[F]] =
    for {
      initialValue <- valueGenerator.generateFreshValue.toResource
      valueRef <- Ref.make[F](initialValue).toResource
      refreshProcess = valueGenerator.generateFreshValue.flatMap(ref.set)
      _ <- refreshProcess.background
    } yield new ValueHolder[F] {
      override final val getValue: F[Value] =
        ref.get
    }
}

trait Logic[F[_]] {
  def run: F[String]
}

object Logic {
  def make[F[_]: Monad](
    valueHolder: ValueHolder[F]
  ): Logic[F] =
    new Logic[F] {
      override final val run: F[String] =
        valueHolder.getValue.map { currentValue =>
          s"The current value is: '${currentValue}'"
        }
    }
}

objects HttpServer {
  private def routes[F[_]: Monad](
    logic: Logic[F]
  ): HttpRoutes[F] = {
    val dsl = Http4sDsl[F]
    import dsl._

    HttpRoutes.of[F] {
      case GET -> Root / "ping"  => Ok("pong")
      case GET -> Root / "value" => Ok(logic.run)
    }
  }

  def make[F[_]: Async](
    logic: Logic[F]
  ): Resource[F, Server] =
    EmberServerBuilder
      .default[F]
      .withPort(port"8080")
      .withHost(host"0.0.0.0")
      .withHttpApp(routes(logic).orNotFound)
      .build
}

